# How to adjust this web page's look?

Tags: html, css, smarty

I'm using Smarty, PHP and HTML. I'm giving you the URL of JS fiddle of my web page. You can see there only first question is contained within a box and all othe questions and their answers are displayed out of the box. I want to display them into the box. I tried lot of tricks but nothing worked for me. So at last I'm asking here. Can anyone help me in this regard? Thanks in advance. The smarty template code and fiddle link where you can see the plain HTML of that page are as follows:
Code from Smarty file:

```
<table class="manage_box" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="1" style="border:1px solid #996633; font-size:13px;" width="100%" >
  <tbody>
{if $all_questions} 
  {assign var='que_seq_no' value=1}
    {foreach from=$all_questions item=qstn_ans key=key}
    <tr>
      <td align="center" colspan="2">
        <table border="0" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
          <tr class="question_info">
            <td valign="top"><b>Question {$que_seq_no}. </b>{if $qstn_ans.question_directions}<br /><b>Direction : </b>{$qstn_ans.question_directions}{/if}<br /><b>Question : </b>{$qstn_ans.question_text}
            </td>
            <td align="right" width="5%" valign="bottom"><b>{$search_ques_id_str}{$qstn_ans.question_id}</b>
            </td>
          </tr>
      {if $test_details.is_test_questions_freez==0 && $all_questions && ($test_details.test_begin_time>$curent_server_time || $test_details.test_mode=='non-schedule') && ($test_details.is_test_lock=='0' || $test_details.is_test_lock=='')}
          <tr class="question_info">
            <td align="right" valign="bottom" colspan="2" width="100%"><a href="change_test_question.php?test_id={$test_details.test_id}&question_id={$qstn_ans.question_id}">Change Question</a>
            </td>
          </tr>
      {/if}

      {if $qstn_ans.question_file}
          <tr class="question_info">
            <td colspan="2"><img src="{$ques_thum_image_path}{$qstn_ans.question_id}_{$qstn_ans.question_file}" />
            </td>
          </tr>
      {/if}
      {if $qstn_ans.question_has_sub_ques==0}
        {if $qstn_ans.answer}
          <tr>
            <td colspan="2">Answers&nbsp;:&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          {foreach from=$qstn_ans.answer item=ans key=ans_no}
          <tr valign="top">
            <td valign="top" colspan="2">
            {if $ans.answer_is_right==1}{assign var='correct_ans' value=$ans_no+1}
            {/if}
            <b style="font-size:13px;">{$ans_no+1}.</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;{if $ans.answer_text!=''}{$ans.answer_text}{/if}<br />
            {if $ans.answer_file!=''}<img src="{$ans_thumb_img_path}{$ans.answer_id}_{$ans.answer_file}" />{/if}
            </td>
          </tr>
          {/foreach}
          <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><b style="font-size:13px;">Correct Answer Option : {$correct_ans}</b></td>
          </tr>
      {/if}
      {else}
        {if $qstn_ans.question_has_sub_ques==1 && $qstn_ans.sub_question}
          {foreach from=$qstn_ans.sub_question item=sub_ques_ans key=sub_ques_no}
          <tr>
            <td valign="top"><b style="font-size:13px;">Sub-question {$que_seq_no}.{$sub_ques_no+1}&nbsp;)&nbsp;&nbsp;</b>{$sub_ques_ans.question_text}
            </td>
            <td align="right" width="5%" valign="bottom"><b>{$search_ques_id_str}{$sub_ques_ans.question_id}</b>
            </td>
          </tr>
            {if $sub_ques_ans.question_file!=''}
          <tr>
            <td valign="top" colspan="2"><img src="{$ques_thum_image_path}{$sub_ques_ans.question_id}_{$sub_ques_ans.question_file}">
            </td>
          </tr>
            {/if}
            {if $sub_ques_ans.answer}
          <tr>
            <td colspan="2">Answer&nbsp;:&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
              {foreach from=$sub_ques_ans.answer item=sub_ans key=sub_ans_no}
          <tr>
            <td valign="top" colspan="2">
                {if $sub_ans.answer_is_right==1} {assign var='correct_sub_ans' value=$sub_ans_no+1} 
                {/if}
              <b style="font-size:13px;">{$sub_ans_no+1}&nbsp;.&nbsp;</b>{if $sub_ansanswer_text!=''}{$sub_ans.answer_text}{/if}<br />
                {if $sub_ans.answer_file!=''}<img src="{$ans_thumb_img_path}{$sub_ans.answer_id}_{$sub_ans.answer_file}" >
                {/if}
            </td>
          </tr>
              {/foreach}
          <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><b style="font-size:13px;">Correct Answer Option : {$correct_sub_ans}</b>
            </td>
          </tr>
            {/if}    
          {/foreach}
        {/if}   
      {/if}
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    {assign var='que_seq_no' value=$que_seq_no+1}
  {/foreach}
  {else}
    <tr>
      <td align="center" colspan="2"><b>No Test Questions Available</b></td>
    </tr>
{/if}                        
  </tbody>
</table>

{literal}
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  $('#close_details').click(function() {
     $('#transperant_popup').hide();
     $('#transperant_popup_content').hide();
     $('#transperant_popup_content').html('');
  });
</script>
{/literal}
```

[JSFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/GRxWN/)

Answer (score 0):

From the JsFiddls I can say that you need to remove the extra  tag genereating after the first question. Only because of that  tag the first question is diaplaying iside a box whereas others are not. To manipulate in a smarty template check the PHP code of fetching all questions, may be the  tag should be coming from the database itself. Other than this there should be no cause of such behavior.